# Titanium Appcelerator - HTTPClient - onload - custom exception

Tags: exception, titanium, httpclient, appcelerator, onload

I am using Titanium Studio (build: 3.4.0.201409261227) and I am trying to catch an exception within the "onload" callback of Ti.Network.HTTPClient.

But that's not possible, I am getting the "Red Screen" with "Application Error" and I am not able to catch the exception.

Anyone an idea?

```
try {
        var tiHTTPClient = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
            onload : function(e) {      
                throw 'EXCEPTION';              
            }
        });     
        tiHTTPClient.open( 'GET', 'http://www.google.com' );
        tiHTTPClient.send();
    }
    catch( e ) {
        alert( 'E: ' + e.message ); 
    }
```

Outside the "onload" function, it's easily possible via:

```
try {
    throw 'EXCEPTION';              
}
catch( e ) {
    alert( 'E: ' + e.message ); 
}
```

Comment: try writing the try catch block inside the onload function.Also add an onerror function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This might be the correct answer or at least the explanation](https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/5141/how-do-you-catch-exceptions-during-asynch-call-backs#answer-15131) :

> BTW, the reason your try...catch blog makes no difference is that "invoke" succeeds -- it's an asynchronous call so it just returns control immediately, and you therefore pass right through the try block without any problems.
>   Blockquote

And one solution could be:

```
    var exceptionHandling = function( msg ) {
        alert( 'E: ' + msg );
    };

    var tiHTTPClient = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
        onload : function(e) {  
            exceptionHandling('EXCEPTION');              
        }
    });     
    tiHTTPClient.open( 'GET', 'http://www.google.com' );
    tiHTTPClient.send();
```